# mongoose not fetching data

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mean

I am trying to fetch all users from a MongoDB database. However for some reason recently the request did not fetch anything.

Here is the code in which I try to fetch the data:

```
app.get('/api/allusers', (req, res) => {
  Employee.find()
    .then(rettrievedData => {
      res.json(rettrievedData)
  });
});
```

Here is the mongoose model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const employeeSchema = mongoose.Schema({

    name: { type: String },
    surName: { type: String },
    mail: { type: String },
    phone: { type: String },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema, 'employee.employees');
```

Here is the code for connecting to Mongo

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://Kiril:xxxxxxxxxxxxx@cluster0-owdfy.mongodb.net/employee?retryWrites=true&w=majority")
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Connected")
  })
```

Also I have checked that there is data in the database, but for some reason the Employee.find() does not retrieve anything. What can be reason?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

why you are adding 'employee.employyes' when you creating your model
try to export the model without it

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema)
```

or better

```
exports.Employee = mongoose.model('Employee', employeeSchema)
```

and require it where you want to use it

```
const Employee = require('path to the schema file')
```

Comment: I have tried that but is not working, strange thing is it was working but when I send the files and build the project on a different PC it broke...

Comment: is it possible that you specify the ips that can connect to your db?